# Project.json not working in Cocos2d-JS

Tags: json, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to develop a game using Cocos2d-JS, but so far I'm only running into stupid problems. Now I have this one and can't for the life of me figure out what I did wrong.

I have this class for a tile sprite:

```
var Tile = cc.Sprite.extend({
    ctor: function(file, params) {
        this._super(file);
    },
});
```

And this guy that extends it:

```
var Goal = Tile.extend({
    ctor: function(params) {
        this._super(res.goal_png, params);
    },
});
```

Which works properly. Now I have this guy, which I later decided I wanted to extend Tile as well:

```
var Block = Tile.extend({
    ctor: function(params) {
        this._super(res.block_png, params);
    },
});
```

However, Cocos2d-JS says no. This is my project.json:

```
{
    "project_type": "javascript",

    "debugMode" : 1,
    "showFPS" : true,
    "frameRate" : 60,
    "id" : "gameCanvas",
    "renderMode" : 0,
    "engineDir":"frameworks/cocos2d-html5",

    "modules" : ["cocos2d"],

    "jsList" : [
        "src/resource.js",
        "src/tiles/Tile.js",
        "src/blocks/Block.js",
        "src/tiles/Goal.js",
        "src/Map.js",
        "src/data.js",
        "src/GameScene.js",
        "src/BackgroundLayer.js",
        "src/AnimationLayer.js",
        "src/StatusLayer.js"
    ]
}
```

I have the Tile.js first, but still the console gives me an error that he doesn't know what Tile is on line 1 of Block.js (also still loads that one first).

I've tried changing project.json, and even deleted it, but the game still compiles, just giving me the error. Do I need to clear some sort of cache?

:(

EDIT: It must be some sort of caching/memory issue, I spent half an hour battling this problem without result. Now I went for a game of LoL, came back and the problem was gone.

Comment: What are you using for editing/running? I've had *very bizarre* issues with the local webserver caching stuff and not refreshing unless you restart the whole proccess (or sometimes even the computer).

Comment: @SebastiánVansteenkiste, I'm using Atom. Should I use the editor + chrome debugger they suggest?

Comment: Not really, you can use whatever is best for you (I usually go with Brackets). The Cocos Code IDE is usefull when you want to debug on Android though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is that I am a dumbass.

Apparently the localhost that gets setup by the cocos command just points to the project folder. And I thought I had to compile my project with every change, causing a new tab to open on every compile (without chrome's devTools), and Chrome was the one caching my files.

Herptiederp